# Barplot with two variables from two dataframes side-by-side

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two dataframes that contain results of two surveys:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option2", "Option1", "Option2")),
                  ID1 = factor(c("Resp1", "Resp1", "Resp3", "Resp4")))

DF2 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option1", "Option2", "Option1", "Option2")),
                  ID2 = factor(c("PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", "PersonD", "PersonE")))
```

The surveys had different respondents, and different numbers of respondents, but both contained the same question; responses to that question are contained in the variable V1 that's present in both dataframes.

I can easily plot V1 separately for both dataframes:

```
plot(DF1$V1)
plot(DF2$V1)
```

Or with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF1, aes(V1, 1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        text = element_text(size=10))
ggplot(DF2, aes(V1, 1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        text = element_text(size=10))
```

But I want to have a plot that displays the contents of V1 in both dataframes side-by-side (in a single plot). How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general strategy would be to summarize the data and put it in the same data.frame, then use separate by fill, color etc.

```
DF1 <- DF1 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF1", n=n())
DF2 <- DF2 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF2", n=n())
DF <- rbind(DF1, DF2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=V1, y=n, fill=DF)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Thank you. One unexpected side effect (that's kind of beyond the scope of the original question) is that while the plots in my example (and analogous plots applied to my actual data) hid NAs, the plot written with your code displays NAs. Do you know why that's the case / how the NAs can be removed from the plot?

Comment: You can take NAs out of your data e.g., by `DF <- DF %>% filter(!is.na(n))`